# cx_freeze not loading modules properly

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, astropy

I am attempting to create a standalone executable but cannot get the compiled exe to run. I have been receiving the error below upon running the exe.

---

[image: error message when running exe]

---

I have ensured proper installation and versions of the following:

```
Python 3.4
cx_freeze 5.0.1
astropy 1.3
numpy 1.12.0
```

The paths that `cx_freeze` is copying from are all from the correct python3.4 directory. In the past I tried to use `pyinstaller` and `py2exe` but both have documented issues with `astropy`. I have tried explicitly including `astropy` in the `build_exe_options` but the error remains.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os', 'astropy']}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [Executable('myscript.py', base=base)]    

setup(name='myscript',
      version='0.1',
      author='me',
      description='my exe test 1',
      options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
      executables=executables)
```

Comment: I don't know about cx_Freeze in particular, but Astropy has had some known issues in the past with application bundlers like PyInstaller and pyexe as well, which you can search for on this site.

Comment: I got Astropy working once with PyInstaller but that was years ago and required some fiddling. If you do some searching you can even find my old pull request to fix some of the issues but it's woefully outdated now and no one has offered to pick up the slack.

Comment: By the way, one of the main issues all of these packages has with Astropy (and not Astropy uniquely) is that they try to do some kind of static analysis to determine only exactly the modules that need to be installed, and sometimes this can fail, and you need to manually specify some 'fixups' for the package. For example, if there are some modules that are loaded dynamically.

Comment: Last comment: You're not likely to get any answers to this from SO, but you should find my old PR to Astropy and note that this is still an open issue.

Comment: Thanks, I figured my attempts were mostly in vain. Is your username the same on the Git Astropy page? I can't seem to find it in the pull requests.

Comment: Here's my original PR: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/960 and apparently I rebased it about a year ago, but it still needed some work.  I'll see if I can find some time to revive this...